# How to SELECT multiple columns with MySQL based on multiple records?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables right now and they look like the following:

The `points` table looks like the following:

```
id  country     points
1   4           1
2   7           5
3   8           4
```

The `sample` table looks like the following:

```
id   iso        pts
1    UK         100
2    US         300
3    AU         700
4    BO         1200
5    BA         1500
6    BR         2000
7    HR         5000
8    TD         10000
9    CA         15000
```

What I basically want is to select ALL data from the `points` table where the `points.country` and `points.points` corresponds to the `sample.iso` and `sample.pts`.

So the result I'd like to achieve is:

```
id  country     points
1   BO          100
2   HR          1500
3   TD          1200
```

Is this actually achievable? If yes, how?

Comment: Your sample results don't correspond to your sample data.

Comment: **@FreeAsInBeer**, it does actually.  The `country` and `points` fields are foreign keys to the `sample` table.

Comment: This is a really weird request though

Comment: @Linger My previous comment wasn't about your relationship between the two tables, but rather that of your tables to the sample results you provided. In your results you have `BO, 100`, but in your tables `BO` is associated with `points = 1` and `pts = 1200`. Please remember for future questions: it's easier to receive constructive answers if you provide logical datasets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to join to the `sample` table twice in order to get the information you are after ([**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/114ec/4/0)):

```
SELECT p.id, s1.iso AS country, s2.pts AS points
FROM points p
INNER JOIN sample s1 ON p.country = s1.id
INNER JOIN sample s2 ON p.points = s2.id
```

Comment: this should be left join [**demo inner join**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e577/6) ,[**demo left join**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e577/9)

Comment: **M Khalid Junaid**,  In the case of the data **Radical_Activity** supplied the INNER JOIN works just fine.  See my SQL Fiddle.  I do agree though if there is a possibility of `country` or `points` not containing a value, then LEFT JOIN should be used.

Comment: @Linger Yes, there is a possibility that country and points does not contain a value. Also may I ask you if this is a common query to do? I'm just doing this way, so if the 'points' table get a new row, it won't be overloaded with information. However I don't know which would be faster. By the way I have about 7 columns like country, points, etc.. The estimated rows in points table will be about 1000-2000, however it will be queried a lot in each hour. So is this solution the best or should I just simply put values into the `points` table?

Comment: **@Radical_Activity**, for all of the joins to the `sample` table you will want to use LEFT JOIN then.  It is pretty common to join to the same table more than once.  However the way you have it is not very common at all because `country` and `points` don't relate to each other at all, yet they are in the same table.  I could see `country` being its own table since a `country` can have a lot of information tied to it.  However, `points` probably would be better off being stored directly in the `points` table, since I am guessing you can expand on `points` any further.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of left join or any join you can do it

```
select t1.id,t1.country,t1.points from table1 as t1 left join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.country
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you're looking for. It's an inner join between `points` and `sample` that matches `points.country` to `sample.id` and `points.points` to `sample.pts`.

The data you supplied doesn't show any `points.points` that match up to `sample.pts` but I think this is what you're were shooting for. If not, please clarify in your question.

```
select p.id, s.iso, s.pts
  from points p, sample s
 where p.country = s.id
   and p.points = s.pts;
```